# Boinc Headless + Computing Preferences. It's possible?

Tags: pi-3b+, headless

I'm running boinc-client (*headless*) with some projects attached over my pi-3b+

I don't seem to find where I could configure the `Computing Preferences` (*cpu/core % usage, ram usage, etc*) that usually are done in the Boinc Client GUI (*as I've on my other Linux setup which has Gnome*). As my rpi has other purpose I don't have X installed and neither I want to install it just to configure this.

Anyone has done this? Which file/properties I must look for/change?
I don't seem to have this short of configuration on the cc_config.xml client.
And the [wiki](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Client_configuration) for the file specifically says:

> (...) Don't use this to limit CPU usage; use computing preferences instead.

But appears that they forgot to explain where/how.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, as the problem is more with BOINC without a GUI rather than the Raspberry Pi itself.

Comment: Affirmative, but when I posted the question I didn't knew and for 15+ days this stayed without any activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this based on a valuable input from an user on the boinc forum. He pointed me to the [global_prefs_override.xml](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Global_prefs_override.xml) file, in which cpu %, cpu time and all the other computing preferences are configured.